# Where column = x or skip?

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a query:

```
SELECT `doc_assign`.`id` as doc_assign_id, 
       `user_profiles`.`data` as report_fixed_template_discount, 
       `doc_assign`.`type` as document_type
FROM (`doc_assign`) 
JOIN `jobs` ON `jobs`.`id` = `job_assign`.`job_id`
JOIN `docs` ON `docs`.`id` = `doc_assign`.`doc_id`
LEFT JOIN `user_profiles` ON `user_profiles`.`user_id` = `jobs`.`client_id`
WHERE `jobs`.`status` =  3
AND `jobs`.`completed_on` >= '2018-09-01 00:00:00'
AND `jobs`.`completed_on` <= '2018-09-30 23:59:59' 
AND `user_profiles`.`meta` =  'report_fixed_template_discount'
```

The problem is that whilst `user_profiles` table will always have data we might not necessarily have rows with `meta = 'report_fixed_template_discount'` - due to which query will not return rows that don't have `meta = 'report_fixed_template_discount'`.

So, the question is how can I see results that may and may not have `meta = 'report_fixed_template_discount'`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can move the condition on `meta` to the left join:

```
SELECT `doc_assign`.`id` as doc_assign_id, 
       `user_profiles`.`data` as report_fixed_template_discount, 
       `doc_assign`.`type` as document_type
FROM (`doc_assign`) 
JOIN `jobs` ON `jobs`.`id` = `job_assign`.`job_id`
JOIN `docs` ON `docs`.`id` = `doc_assign`.`doc_id`
LEFT JOIN `user_profiles` ON `user_profiles`.`user_id` = `jobs`.`client_id`
AND `user_profiles`.`meta` =  'report_fixed_template_discount' -- Here!
WHERE `jobs`.`status` =  3
AND `jobs`.`completed_on` >= '2018-09-01 00:00:00'
AND `jobs`.`completed_on` <= '2018-09-30 23:59:59'
```